# Boyce Codd Normal Form Decomposition second Relationship

Tags: database-design, relational-database, relationship

I have this Relationship and am trying to decompose it into Boyce Codd Normal Form  :

```
  Relationship   R(workerName, pay, project, budgetAllocated, jobRole ) 

        having key (workerName, project)

        And the following Functional Dependencies:

        workerName  -> pay 
        project -> budgetAllocated
        workerName, project -> Role

I have come with this output so far, is this output correct?

    workerName, project ->Role
    project -> budgetAllocated, pay
 i know the first Relationship is in BCNF because of the super key (workerName, project )

what about the second ?

Using the Algorithm:

S = {ABCDE}       // Intialization S = {R}
S = {ACDE, AB}    // Pick FD: A->B which violates BCNF
S = {ACE, AB, CD} // Pick FD: C->D which violates BCNF
// Return S as all relations are in BCNF


R(workerName, pay, project, budgetAllocated, jobRole ) 


workerName  -> pay 
project -> budgetAllocated
workerName, project -> Role

S = {workerName, pay, project, budgetAllocated, jobRole }           // Intialization S = {R}
S = {(project,budgetAllocated, jobRole) , (workerName, pay )       // Pick FD: workerName -> pay which violates BCNF
S = {(jobRole), (workerName, pay ) , (project, budgetAllocated)    // Pick FD: project -> budgetAllocated which violates BCNF
```

where was i going wrong in these steps as I ended with jobRole but no super key

(workerName, project) ?

Comment: How do you get `project -> pay` in your second result from the given functional dependencies?

Comment: @reaanb i am trying to follow this algorithm S = {ABCDE}       // Intialization S = {R}
S = {ACDE, AB}    // Pick FD: A->B which violates BCNF
S = {ACE, AB, CD} // Pick FD: C->D which violates BCNF
// Return S as all relations are in BCNF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer, I assume that `jobRole` and `Role` are the same attribute.

To decompose in BCNF, you should start by finding a dependency that violates this form, that is in which the determinant is not a superkey.

For instance, in this case, the dependency `project → budgetAllocated` violates the BCNF since `project` is not a superkey. Then you should decompose the original relation in two parts, one with the attributes determinates by `project`, and one with the remaining attributes + `project`, i.e.:

```
R1(project, budgetAllocated) {project → budgetAllocated}
R2(workerName, pay, project, Role) {workerName → pay, project workerName → Role}
```

Now, `R1` is in BCNF, since the determinant of the dependency is a key, while `R2` must be decomposed, since its key is `project, workerName`, while the dependency `workerName → pay` violates the normal form.

So, at the second step, we decompose `R2` in:

```
R3(pay workerName) {workerName → pay}
R4(Role project workerName) {project workerName → Role}
```

So, at the end, the correct decomposition is `R1`, `R3` and `R4`, and all the dependencies are preserved.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. i have just made  a few edits to my original question, by following this algorithm which steps did I miss?

Comment: The error is that when you select a dependency that violates the normal form, you remove *all* the attributes from the relation, while you should remove *only* the attributes determinated, *not* the determinant (the LHS).